# ImagePicker memory warning crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

In didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo I'm normalizing the image but I`m getting Received Memory warning and crash in some devices when I take a picture . Why?

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker 

didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
    {
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
        // Save image

        image = [self normalizedImage:image];

      //  UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
        self.image = image;
        [self salvarImagem:image];
    }

- (UIImage *)normalizedImage:(UIImage*)imgtratar {
    if (imgtratar.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationUp) return imgtratar; 

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imgtratar.size, NO, imgtratar.scale);
    [imgtratar drawInRect:(CGRect){0, 0, imgtratar.size}];
    UIImage *normalizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return normalizedImage;
}
```

EDIT: I have already searched and the solutions don't work for me...
I debugged and the error is in

```
  [imgtratar drawInRect:(CGRect){0, 0, imgtratar.size}];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem resizing the image...the problem was because the image was too big

```
- (UIImage *)normalizedImage:(UIImage*)imgtratar {
    if (imgtratar.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationUp) return imgtratar; 

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(117, 175));
    [imgtratar drawInRect:(CGRect){0, 0, 117, 175}];
    UIImage *normalizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return normalizedImage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because you forgot the line

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

right after `UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];`

And/Or compress and convert the image to JPEG format.Check `UIImageJPEGRepresentation(UIImage *image, CGFloat compressionQuality)`.

**N.B.** Please search first for existing solution. you will find some [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834128/memory-warning-after-using-the-uiimagepicker-once), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20119918/memory-warning-when-using-uiimagepickercontroller) and lots in [here](https://www.google.com.bd/search?q=UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=sb&gws_rd=cr&ei=MpbjU4CgN8-eugScrIJo#channel=sb&q=UIImagePicker+memory+warning&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&spell=1)

Comment: I did search but these solutions doesn't work for me

Comment: I debugged my code and the problem is when I try normalize the image